# Binary interpolation to find a polynomial root always outputs 0.00

Tags: c, polynomials

I use binary interpolation to find a polynomial root between values `a` and `b` (with `a < b`), but the output is always `0.00`, I really can't solve it.

Below is my C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

float fx(int a3, int a2, int a1, int a0, float x) {
    return a3 * pow(x, 3) + a2 * pow(x, 2) + a1 * x + a0;
}

float binary(int a3, int a2, int a1, int a0, float a, float b, float *result)
{
    float fa = fx(a3, a2, a1, a0, a), fb = fx(a3, a2, a1, a0, b);
    float mid = (a + b) / 2;
    float fmid = fx(a3, a2, a1, a0, mid);
    float root = 0.0;
    if (b - a >= 0.001) {
        if (fa * fb >= 0) {
            *result = 0;
            return 0;
        }
        if (fa * fb < 0)//
        {
            if (fmid == 0) {
                *result = mid;
                return 0;
            }
            else if (fmid * fa > 0) {
                a = mid;
                root = binary(a3, a2, a1, a0, a, b, result);
            }
            else if (fmid * fb > 0) {
                b = mid;
                root = binary(a3, a2, a1, a0, a, b, result);
            }
        }
    }
    *result = mid;
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int a3, a2, a1, a0;
    float a, b, result;

    scanf("%d %d %d %d", &a3, &a2, &a1, &a0);
    scanf("%f %f", &a, &b);
    float output = binary(a3, a2, a1, a0, a, b, &result);
    printf("%.2lf", output);
    return 0;
}
```

I believe that when using the `binary` function, I employed recursion. While I successfully found the result through recursion, it did not return the correct value. Upon using the debugger in VSCode, I observed that the final value I found was correct, yet the function did not return the expected result. My test data includes `a3 = 3, a2 = -1, a1 = -3, a0 = 1`. The expected output is `0.33`, but the actual output is `0.00`.

Please help me! I am just a grade one student, I have spent one night trying to solve it!!!

Comment: You haven't told us what the input of `a` and `b` are.  I suggest you edit your question hard-code that failing test case in `main()`.

Comment: Btw, C doesn't guarantee tail-call optimization so you should prefer an iterative solution to control the stack size.

Comment: You probably want to use your `root` variable from the recursion for something.  Also, unless you have a specific reason prefer using `double` instead of `float`.

Comment: For readability prefer 1 variable definition per line, i.e. move the definition of `fb` to the next line.

Comment: Don't confuse effort with result.  Life only rewards the latter.

Comment: `b - a >= 0.001` looks like a magnitude test.  You may want to do `fabs(b-a) > 0.001`  if `a > b` and because floating point values are approximate we don't usually compare those for equality.

Comment: my variable a is -0.5 and b is 0.5

Comment: You want to edit your question to add that information (and delete the comment).

Comment: Please accept the best answer below by clicking on the check mark next to it.

Answer (score 1):

`binary()` returns `0` in all cases and this is the value you assign to the `output` variable which is what you print.  You could `return` the result and eliminate the `result` argument, `result` and `root` variables along these lines:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

double fx(int a3, int a2, int a1, int a0, double x) {
    return a3 * pow(x, 3) + a2 * pow(x, 2) + a1 * x + a0;
}

double binary(int a3, int a2, int a1, int a0, double a, double b) {
    double fa = fx(a3, a2, a1, a0, a);
    double fb = fx(a3, a2, a1, a0, b);
    double mid = (a + b)/2;
    double fmid = fx(a3, a2, a1, a0, mid);
    if (fabs(b - a) > 0.001) {
        if (fa * fb >= 0)
            return NAN;
        if (!fmid)
            return mid;
        if(fmid * fa > 0)
            return binary(a3, a2, a1, a0, mid, b);
        if(fmid * fb > 0)
            return binary(a3, a2, a1, a0, a, mid);
    }
    return mid;
}

int main(void) {
    int a3, a2, a1, a0;
    double a, b;
    scanf("%d %d %d %d", &a3, &a2, &a1, &a0);
    scanf("%lf %lf", &a, &b);
    printf("%.2lf\n", binary(a3, a2, a1, a0, a, b));
}
```

Example run:

```
3 -1 -3 1
-0.5 0.5
0.33
```

The error case `if (fa * fb >= 0)` you can handle with a separate argument/return value (see @chgrlie's answer).  This should show you your default design.  To show you something different you could also return `NAN` to let caller know the value is invalid.  Only do this when you values in your value domain that are truly different (like a negative value when you expect a positive result).

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems:

- The function `binary` always returns `0`.  The return value is not the root value, which is stored into `*result`, it should be an indicator of success: eg: the function fails if `fx(a)` and `fx(b)` have the same sign.
- you should return the result of the recursive call instead of storing it into `root` and forgetting about it, finally storing the initial value of `mid` into `*result`.
- using `pow` with potentially negative values is not recommended. Use nested multiplications instead.
- there are multiple redundant tests.
- you should test for `scanf()` failure to convert the expected input values.
- the test `b - a < 0.001` is questionable but consistent with the precision of the output using `%.2f`. You did mention the constraint `a < b`, but it would be better to use `fabs(b - a) < 0.001`, which removes the constraint and is more explicit.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

float fx(int a3, int a2, int a1, int a0, float x) {
    return ((a3 * x + a2) * x + a1) * x + a0;
}

int binary(int a3, int a2, int a1, int a0, float a, float b, float *result) {
    float fa = fx(a3, a2, a1, a0, a);
    float fb = fx(a3, a2, a1, a0, b);
    float mid = (a + b) / 2;
    float fmid = fx(a3, a2, a1, a0, mid);

    if (fa == 0) {
        *result = a;
        return 1;
    }
    if (fb == 0) {
        *result = b;
        return 1;
    }
    if (fmid == 0 || fabs(b - a) < 0.001) {
        *result = mid;
        return 1;
    }
    if (fa * fb > 0) {
        // failure: function has the sign sign on boundaries
        *result = mid;
        return 0;
    }
    if (fmid * fa > 0) {
        // interpolate between mid and b
        return binary(a3, a2, a1, a0, mid, b, result);
    } else {
        // interpolate between a and mid
        return binary(a3, a2, a1, a0, a, mid, result);
    }
}

int main() {
    int a3, a2, a1, a0;
    float a, b, result;

    if (scanf("%d %d %d %d", &a3, &a2, &a1, &a0) != 4)
        return 1;
    if (scanf("%f %f", &a, &b) != 2)
        return 1;
    int success = binary(a3, a2, a1, a0, a, b, &result);
    printf("success=%d, result=%.2f\n", success, result);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that the above implementation recomputes the boundary values at each recursive step, whereas it would be much more efficient to use a loop and only compute the value at the mid point.

Here is a non recursive implementation:

```
int binary(int a3, int a2, int a1, int a0, float a, float b, float *result) {
    float fa = fx(a3, a2, a1, a0, a);
    float fb = fx(a3, a2, a1, a0, b);

    if (fa == 0) {
        *result = a;
        return 1;
    }
    if (fb == 0) {
        *result = b;
        return 1;
    }
    if (fa * fb >= 0) {
        // failure: function has the sign sign on boundaries
        *result = 0;
        return 0;
    }

    for (;;) {
        float mid = (a + b) / 2;
        float fmid = fx(a3, a2, a1, a0, mid);

        if (fmid == 0 || fabs(b - a) < 0.001) {
            *result = mid;
            return 1;
        }
        if (fa * fmid > 0) {
            // interpolate between mid and b
            a = mid;
            fa = fmid;
        } else {
            // interpolate between a and mid
            b = mid;
            fb = fmid;
        }
    }
}
```